# Curious with ++ and double casts

Tags: java, casting, increment

So again I was looking at code and I found this.

```
   public ProtoTableShapedRecipe addRecipe(ItemStack stack, Object ... varargs){
   int i = 0;
   ...
   ...
   ...
   String[] astring = (String[])((String[])varargs[i++]);
   }
```

The thing I was wondering about is why is there a need for a two casts of String[] and when it comes to passing the variable `i` to `varargs[]` would it considered value 1 and making `i` 1 or is it just adding 1 to `i` when it is being passed and `i` stays at 0.

Comment: I think the first `String[]` is to cast `varargs`, while the second `String[]` is to cast `varargs[i++]`.

Comment: @tang, nope. Both are used to cast the `varargs[i++]`. One of them is useless.

Answer (score 2):

In reverse order, first the `i` value is used in the array index (so `varargs[0]`) and then `i` is incremented so that *on the next line* `i` is `1`.

Next, because the `varargs` or type `Object[]`. It's only safe to use that cast only if it takes `String[]`(s) (and you forgot the opening `{`). Something like

```
public ProtoTableShapedRecipe addRecipe(ItemStack stack,
        String[]... varargs) {
    int i = 0;
    // ...
    String[] astring = varargs[i++]; // <-- varargs[0]
    // i = 1
}
```

Comment: Ok. that make sense with i. As for the casting this is code there is more to the `Object...` there is another part that calls this, where both `String` and `String[]` could be passed. It checks if it `instanceof` either in `if` statement and changes the cast accordingly. I understand the point of casting. I just didn't know why it was double like it is later one it is casted for a string like `String s2 = (String)varargs[i++];` So it threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

Double cast is unnecessary here. Just a single cast will suffice:

```
String[] astring = (String[])varargs[i++];
```

Modern IDEs issue an unnecessary cast warning at this line.

Comment: ah Ok. Thats what I thought, maybe the person put one there cause it was yelling at them to do so. Didn't think there would be a reason. I always thought once it gets cast then it's cast.